# Get image width while uploading image PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading

in my code, while a user is uploading a pic, in my php code i want to read the width of the image while its getting uploaded, below is my code --

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');

    $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."AndroidApp/VideoUploads/Thumbnails/";

    $emailid=$_GET['emailid'];
    $randNum=$_GET['randNum'];
    $ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']) ;
    $thumb_url="DoUpNow_Funny_Video_Thumb"."_".$randNum.".".$ext;

    $file_path = $file_path.$thumb_url;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){

        list($width) = getimagesize($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);

        $stmt2 = $linkID1->prepare("update VideoUploads set video_thumb=?, width=? where emailid=? and randNum=?");
        $stmt2->bind_param("ssss", $thumb_url,$width,$emailid,$randNum);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->close();
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }

    function findexts ($filename) 
     { 
     $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
     $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
     $n = count($exts)-1; 
     $exts = $exts[$n]; 
     return $exts; 
     }
?>
```

The file is getting uploaded, but there is no value in the width variable, is anything wrong, or my approach is wrong.

Comment: It's always after it's uploaded. That's why I think you should use you `$file_path` for getting the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file), the `tmp_name` variable refers to a file which no longer exists, it was moved.

> If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

So, use `$file_path` to get your file informations :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    list($width) = getimagesize($file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it's working fine
check this and let me

```
 <?php
 $image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);
 $image_width = $image_info[0];
 $image_height = $image_info[1];
 ?>
```